# Q3support status in the next Qt release

Tags: qt, qt4, qt3

What is the status of q3support classes in the next Qt release, I heard that before august when next major Qt release it will be done without Qt3 support is that true? please give me links if that is true.

And what is the proposed ways to reduce the q3 dependencies.

Comment: "I heard that"....where did you hear that?

Comment: I am asking for links :)

Comment: That's all fine and well, but you're asking for information which we're unlikely to have, based on a rumor for which you don't state where you got that from. I would say as long as it's not officially announced by Qt/Nokia, there's not much to say.

Comment: *which we're unlikely to have* I don't think there is a collective identity at StackoverFlow, at least not one that I am part of. It is a legitimate question. There are plenty of questions asked every day that aren't and it's better to spend downvotes on and criticize them, isn't it?

Comment: @TamásSzelei 1) I didn't downvote although I am critical of the question. 2) If there is any reliable information about a company's product releases or support, it's most likely to come from the company 3) Given the answer by Kamil, that's exactly where the relevant information came from in the end. (And perhaps where the OP heard it in the first place)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go: http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/05/12/qt-modules-maturity-level-the-list/

For future... why won't use google? Qt3Support is already deprecated and will be dropped in Qt5. And the proposed way to reduce Qt3 dependencies is: (drums) PORT YOUR CODE TO Qt4! Qt 4.0 was released almost SEVEN years ago! Yes, Qt 4.0 was released in 2005! Why didn't you (or your dev team) do anything about this in seven years? The Qt3Support module is well documented like most of Qt's libraries. Just use the docs and port everything, class by class.